# Trouble creating array of JSON objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Well! I have to create an array of JSON objects something like:

```
[object, object, object...]
```

and for that I take all selected rows in my jtable of jquery, creating a single object with all parameters for each row
and at end of record reading I add that object to a previous array, this:

```
var myObject = new Array();
$selectedRows.each(function () {
    var record = $(this).data('record');
    var id = record.id;
    var proyecto = record.proyecto;
    var tarea = record.tarea;
    var fase = record.fase;
    var name = record.name;
    var timeStart = record.timeStart;
    var timeEnd = record.timeEnd;
    var duracion = record.duracion;
    var facturada = record.facturada;
    var activa = record.deleted;

    var actividad = [{id:id,proyecto:proyecto, tarea:tarea,tarea:tarea,fase:fase,name:name,timeStart:timeStart,timeEnd:timeEnd,duracion:duracion,facturada:facturada,activa:activa }];

    myObject.push(actividad);
});
```

Chrome console sais that I created an Array that have Arrays that have each one its correlative object, something like:
[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1] ... ] My objects are inside that arrays
Can I convert it to:

```
[object, object, object...]
```

???

Comment: note. this has absolutely nothing to do with json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
var actividad = [{id:id,proyecto:proyecto, tarea:tarea,tarea:tarea,fase:fase,name:name,timeStart:timeStart,timeEnd:timeEnd,duracion:duracion,facturada:facturada,activa:activa }];
```

to

```
var actividad = {id:id,proyecto:proyecto, tarea:tarea,tarea:tarea,fase:fase,name:name,timeStart:timeStart,timeEnd:timeEnd,duracion:duracion,facturada:facturada,activa:activa };
```

The first one creates an array with an object inside it, the second one creates an object. If you push the first one to `myObject`, the result will be `[[{Object}]]`. This is why you see `[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1] ... ]`.